# Blue screen error after replacing CMOS battery

Tags: windows-7, bios, desktop, cmos

I have two problems with my desktop.
1. CMOS battery down hence date and time reset every time after PC shutdown.
2. Display does not appear with beep sound.

I have tried by removing RAM and inserting again after cleaning RAM and slot.It doesn't worked.
After I replaced CMOS battery second issue resolved but blue screen error come.Also tried by reseting bios from bios setting but doesn't worked.I have attached blue screen error screenshots.
[image: blue screen error 1]

[image: blue screen error 2]

Comment: Make sure you have the date and time set properly in the BIOS now that it has been reset.